# How to aggregate results against a scrolling 1 hour window

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table that that contains delivery records for vehicles arriving at a location. (one unique record for each journey). I can monitor the busy periods by aggregating by hour using something like this...

```
select count(*), LOCATION, date_trunc('hour',ARRIVALTIME)
from ARRIVALS
group by LOCATION, date_trunc('hour',ARRIVALTIME)
order by LOCATION, date_trunc('hour',ARRIVALTIME) desc
```

I can use this (with minor mods) to find the busiest 1 hour period at each location. However, this has limitation, it only aggregates against full chronological hours i.e. between 1 o'clock and 2 o'clock, and then 2 o'clock and 3 o'clock etc.

Question - how do I find the busiest 60 minute 'rolling window' of the day?

Consider this as an example. If I have one arrival every two minutes between 13:30 and 14:30 (and no others) then the query I've shown above will tell me that the period 1 till 2 had 15 deliveries and so did the period 2 till 3. What I really want is a query that will tell me my busiest 60 minutes was 30 deliveries between 13:30 and 14:30.

I'm using postgres version 10.5

```
DROP TABLE arrival;
CREATE TABLE arrival (  location CHAR(15),  arrivalTime TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 09:45:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 09:50:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 09:55:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 09:59:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 10:10:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 10:15:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('LONDON','01-Jan-2000 10:25:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('PARIS','01-Jan-2000 09:58:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('PARIS','01-Jan-2000 10:01:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('PARIS','01-Jan-2000 10:02:00');
INSERT INTO arrival (location,arrivalTime) VALUES('PARIS','01-Jan-2000 11:02:00');
```

The two suggests so far both error with 'RANGE FOLLOWING is only supported with UNBOUNDED'. 'RANGE' is new to me so I'm currently doing some reading.

UPDATE - Ok, so it appears that 'RANGE' requires version 11. Anyone know if there's a work-around?

Comment: Might be better asked at sister site https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions with the `range` window specifier:

```
select a.*,
       count(*) over (order by arrivaltime
                      range between current row and '1 hour'::interval following
                     ) as hourcnt
from arrivals a
order by hourcnt desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres 11 this works (because I have no sample data to test this is just a sketch)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY arrivaltime RANGE BETWEEN interval '30 minutes' PRECEDING AND interval '30 minutes' FOLLOWING)
FROM
    arrival
ORDER BY count DESC
```

The [RANGE window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html) counts for every ordered record all records with timestamp 30 minutes before and after. Of course this could be adjusted to fit your use case better (maybe `BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND interval '1 hour' FOLLOWING`)

[Further reading](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/05/postgresql-11s-support-for-sql-standard-groups-and-exclude-window-function-clauses/)